# reactive form in angular : column display

Tags: angular, datagrid, angular-reactive-forms, angular12

I would try to implement in Web App a form written in Excel
[image]

having some fields, arranged somehow in a Excel grid...

Some of the fields are editable by user, some others are calculated by the application

What are the ways to implement that in Angular, using Reactive forms (dynamically generated)?

Is there a Grid or Matrix display that I would associate for each dynamic field the Row and Column properties?

Answer (score 0):

Here with I have provided a sample for your reference for reactive forms in angular.
The provided code is a dynamic registration form where the user can register the required details.

component.ts:

```
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
    
    import { ListingService } from '../service/listing.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-register',
      templateUrl: './register.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
    })
    export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    
      RegisterForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
    
    
      constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public service: ListingService, private toastr: ToastrService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.RegisterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          'username': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          'firstname': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          'lastname': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          'gender': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          'password': new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    
        })
      }
    
      onSubmit() {
        this.service.userRegister(this.RegisterForm.value).subscribe(data => { console.log("User Created") }, err => {
          if (err.status == 400)
            this.toastr.error('Username is already Exist', 'Registeration Failed.');
          else
            console.log(err);
        })
      }

HTML:

<style>
body { background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/book-stack-library-room-blurred-260nw-621157613.jpg"); background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
</style>
<body class="img1">



  <div class=" container bg-light p-4 " style="width: 50%; margin-top: 40px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #ccc">
    <h2 class="text-center">Add User</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="RegisterForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3 mb-3 " formControlName="username" placeholder="user Name" />
        <small *ngIf="RegisterForm.get('username')?.invalid && RegisterForm.get('username')?.touched" class="text-danger">User Name is required</small>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3 mb-3 " formControlName="firstname" placeholder="first Name" />
        <small *ngIf="RegisterForm.get('firstname')?.invalid && RegisterForm.get('firstname')?.touched" class="text-danger">first Name is required</small>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3 mb-3 " formControlName="lastname" placeholder="last Name" />
        <small *ngIf="RegisterForm.get('lastname')?.invalid && RegisterForm.get('lastname')?.touched" class="text-danger">last Name is required</small>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3 mb-3 " formControlName="gender" placeholder="gender" />
        <small *ngIf="RegisterForm.get('gender')?.invalid && RegisterForm.get('gender')?.touched" class="text-danger">gender is required</small>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3 mb-3 " formControlName="password" placeholder="password" />
        <small *ngIf="RegisterForm.get('password')?.invalid && RegisterForm.get('password')?.touched" class="text-danger">password is required</small>
      </div>





      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <button [disabled]="RegisterForm?.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

[image: Registration form-image]

```
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for the example, but where are different columns?